# Remove all subviews in dealloc?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, uiview

My current understanding is that superviews have retains each of their subviews.  For a subclass of a UIView, do I need to remove all of my subviews from their superview as part of dealloc? I'm currently just releasing my IBOutlets, removing observed notifications, and clearing up any pesky ivars.

Or is removing and releasing subviews part of a UIView's [super dealloc]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIView retains its subviews, so it's responsible for releasing them. Your subclass doesn't own those views (unless you explicitly retain them), so you don't need to worry about releasing them.

So it sounds like you're doing the right thing.

Answer (score 4):

As a part of the view's dealloc, the subviews are removed automatically.  So you don't need to remove them.  However, if your view has retained any of its subviews [aside from the automatic retain], you should release them during dealloc.

So for example suppose your view contained the following code:

[header file]

```
 UILabel *myLabel;  
 @property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *myLabel;
```

[implementation file]

```
 someLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame: someFrame];
 [self addSubview: someLabel];
 self.myLabel = someLabel;
 [someLabel release];  // now retained twice, once by the property and once as a subview

 someButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame: someOtherFrame];
 [self addSubview: someButton];
 [someButton release];  // retained once as it is a subview
```

then your dealloc method would look like this:

```
 - (void) dealloc {
   [myLabel release];
   [super dealloc];
 }
```